# CSS Drop down menu - Sub Items appear to far right of Div

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I wanted to created a hoverable, drop-down menu for a html page. I created what I thought was correct HTML/CSS but the hover items appear on the far left side of the banner div. I've created a JSFIddle of the 'offending'code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4CCdv/2/

Html:

```
<div id="Header">
        <p></p>
        <ul class="Menu">
            <li class="Menu">Home</li>
            <li class="Menu" >Item2
                <ul class="Menu">
                    <li class="Menu">Sub A</li>
                    <li class="Menu">Sub B</li>
                    <li class="Menu">Sub C</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu" >Item 3
                <ul class="Menu">
                    <li>Sub A</li>
                    <li>Sub B</li>
                    <li>Sub C</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu" >Item 4
                <ul class="Menu">
                    <li>Sub A</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu" >Item4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#Header {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 85.5%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 95px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0066ff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align:center;
}

.Menu {
    background-color: #2fa4e7;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #2fa4e7 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
    border-color: #1995dc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0.2em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0024d9;
}

.Menu ul {
    display: none;
}

.Menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 100%;
}
```

I've been hammering at this for a while, but can't figure out why it would matter that there is a parent div or why the submenus try and appear outside of it. Any ideas?

Comment: u need to give different class name for parent and child `<ul>`

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/4CCdv/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Check out this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4CCdv/3/)**. You have to give parent `li` `position:relative` and child `ul` `position:absolute`

CSS

```
ul.Menu li {
    position: relative;
}
ul.Menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That did it. I noticed you added the parent element to the CSS selectors (ul.Menu). Was that a best practice or a personal practice?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add relative position to the parent element of your hover. this way you can position child element according to parent not to whole page.

here it is:

```
.Menu li {
    position:relative;
}
```

Now you can play with left, right, top, bottom to place your menu wherever you want